# Phrase search in Youtube API

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

in Version 2.0 of Youtube's API (discontinued), the API documentation specified a logic of how to formulate the compound/phrase search, what is the equivalent information for API v3.0?

What do i need to do to convert my keywords to work on API v3.0?

Here is the text for the v2.0:

> The q parameter specifies a search query term. YouTube will search all
> video metadata for videos matching the term. Video metadata includes
> titles, keywords, descriptions, authors' usernames, and categories.
> Note that any spaces, quotes or other punctuation in the parameter
> value must be URL-escaped.
>
> To search for an exact phrase, enclose the
> phrase in quotation marks. For example, to search for videos matching
> the phrase "spy plane", set the q parameter to %22spy+plane%22. Your
> request can also use the Boolean NOT (-) and OR (|) operators to
> exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of
> several search terms. For example, to search for videos matching
> either "boating" or "sailing", set the q parameter to
> boating|sailing. (Note that the pipe character must be URL-escaped.)
> Similarly, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing"
> but not "fishing", set the q parameter to boating|sailing+-fishing.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if this api filter seem to be the same : here example with youtube and wikipedia. As you can show on browser debugger all parameters is sending to the param "q" with pipe "|" ...

```
window.searchModule = {

  cors: "http://crossorigin.me/",
  wikiEndpoint: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php",
  ytEndpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search",
  ytKey: "AIzaSyDsPK3Cs1A4ipMjNr147ubG5HpoDyW6zzk",

  init: function(sentSearch) {
    var self = this,
        bandCheck = $("#bandCheckbox").is(":checked");

    if(bandCheck == true) {
      sentSearch = sentSearch + "+(band)";
    }

    self.wikiSearch(sentSearch);
    self.ytSearch(sentSearch);
    self.watchers();
  },

  wikiSearch: function(sentSearch) {
    var self = this;

    $.ajax({
      url: self.cors + self.wikiEndpoint + "?action=query&list=search&srsearch=" + sentSearch + "&srlimit=1&format=json",
      success: function(response) {
        //console.log(response.query);
        self.formatWiki(response.query);
      },

      error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    })
  } .....
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqmgGB

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried,

```
q: '\b(billy the cat)\b',
```